# Trying to instanciate interface javax.persistence.Table with unknown elements

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, entity, runtimeexception

I've tried to create the Entity in Java EE 7. Hibernate Version -5.1.0, jta -4.0.4, jpa -2.1.

Here my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="bookUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <mapping-file>src/BookEntity.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>src.BookEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

JUnit file where i trying to create entity manager factory:

```
@Test
public void Test(){

    BookEntity book = new BookEntity();
    book.setTitle("What is love?");
    book.setDescription("What is Love? Answer: Read this book");
    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bookUnit").createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(em);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.flush();
    assert em.contains(book);
    em.close();

}
```

}

```
@Entity
public class BookEntity {
private long id;
private String title;
private Double price;
private String description;

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "title", nullable = true, length = 255)
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


@Basic
@Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 255)
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    BookEntity that = (BookEntity) o;

    if (id != that.id) return false;
    if (title != null ? !title.equals(that.title) : that.title != null) return false;
    if (price != null ? !price.equals(that.price) : that.price != null) return false;
    if (description != null ? !description.equals(that.description) : that.description != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (price != null ? price.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

BookEntity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<entity class="src.BookEntity">
    <table name="book" schema="public" catalog="test_db"/>
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" precision="0"/>
        </id>
        <basic name="title">
            <column name="title" nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="price">
            <column name="price" nullable="false" precision="-1"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="description">
            <column name="description" nullable="false"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
   </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

And I've recieve this Exception:

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory

at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at test.test.Test(test.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Trying to instanciate interface          
javax.persistence.Table with unknown elements   at org.hibernate.annotations.common.annotationfactory.AnnotationProxy.getAnnotationValues(AnnotationProxy.java:88)
at org.hibernate.annotations.common.annotationfactory.AnnotationProxy.<init>(AnnotationProxy.java:69)
at org.hibernate.annotations.common.annotationfactory.AnnotationFactory.create(AnnotationFactory.java:80)
at org.hibernate.annotations.common.annotationfactory.AnnotationFactory.create(AnnotationFactory.java:53)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.getTable(JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.java:2780)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.initAnnotations(JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.java:345)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.isAnnotationPresent(JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.java:314)
at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXAnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(JavaXAnnotatedElement.java:60)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.categorizeAnnotatedClass(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:115)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:104)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:876)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
... 30 more
```

I've searched solution of this exception, but solutions don't help me

Comment: Where's the `src/BookEntity.xml` and the Java source for the `BookEntity` class?

Comment: Why are you using a mapping-file? I've never used mapping files, but you should be using mapping files OR annotations. I don't think both will work. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010435/difference-between-hibernate-mapping-file-and-annotation

Comment: Thank You, it helped. I'm new to JPA