# Hibernate Java Config Versus Xml

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I don't fully understand how to choose between java configuration and xml in hibernate config file? Tutorials that I have watched seem to be out of date. So my question is what is the best and most up to date way of configuring a model to hibernate.

The following is my current approach which seems to be the only one working for me:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>


<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect</property>

<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>

<!-- <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property> -->
```

I am configuring my model in a java file as shown below:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {

        // Create your SessionFactory with mappings for every Entity in a specific package
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PersonModel.class);

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        //SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of doing it? or should it be done via XML file, if so can someone show me an example please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you use spring as well, you can pack the dataSource inside your application.xml and map your classes with jpa

Comment: For now I want to use Hibernate on its own easier to learn for me

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following docs for examples:

For annotation mapping:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping

For xml mapping:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/fr-FR/html/xml.html

Use of one of them it's up to you, for more details you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147018/hibernate-annotation-or-xml-configuration) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010435/difference-between-hibernate-mapping-file-and-annotation)

**EDIT:  mapping example in hibernate configuration file**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping package="test.animals"/>
    <mapping class="test.Flight"/>
    <mapping class="test.Sky"/>
    <mapping class="test.Person"/>
    <mapping class="test.animals.Dog"/>
    <mapping resource="test/animals/orm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I am using annotations in my model class, but I still need to use the following code:
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PersonModel.class);
Is there an alternative or is this the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Kris22 Yes this way is correct but you can alternatively add your mapping into hibernate configuration file with mapping tag ex : `<mapping class="yourpackage.PersonModel"/>` and thus you dont need `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PersonModel.class);` in your java

Comment: @Kris22 i've updated my answer with an example of xml config

Comment: Thank you this is very useful

Comment: @Kris22 Among advantages of Java config over xml i can quote that with java config you can benefit from type safety and this can save you time , also refactoring and search will be more easier.

Comment: @Kris22 Also i realize that your question was more about hibernate java config versus xml config and not annotation versus xml mapping, if so feel free to approve my edit

Answer (score 0):

This way you can scan all entity classes at once

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(yourDataSource())
        .scanPackages("com.yourpackage.name")
        .addProperties(properties)
        .buildSessionFactory();
```