# Spring Application Context configuration: class not found exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

When I start my web application, I get from init():

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
```

maybe I miss something I my configuration files.

In pom.xml I have this 2 spring dependencies:

```
[...]
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
[...]
```

and in Datasource.xml I have beans and listener declared:

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Rubrica" />
<property name="username" value="user" />
<property name="password" value="pass" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="JDBC_Spring_EntryDAO" class="net.tirasa.jdbc_spring_addressbook.JDBC_Spring_EntryDAO">  
<property name="JDBC_Spring_EntryDAO" ref="JDBC_Spring_EntryDAO" />
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>

</beans>

<listener>
  <listenerclass>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The log message switched misteriously to

```
class path resource [Spring-Datasource.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

That is good to me, since it looks like I have to put the Spring-Datasource.xml file into the right path, or I have to specify the right path in the command line

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Datasource.xml");
    dataSource = (DataSource) context.getBean("JDBC_Spring_EntryDAO");
```

Comment: `2.5.6.SEC03` what? Why are you using XML config with Spring 4? My eyes...

Comment: what do I have to use?

Comment: Annotation based config using Java. XML is so 2000

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162278/benefits-of-javaconfig-over-xml-configurations-in-spring)

Answer (score 2):

Use Spring 4 core and context:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```