# What is the difference between Spring mvc annotation based and apring mvc xml based?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am learning spring mvc and I checked few online sites for the same but To me Spring mvc annotation based and apring mvc xml based looks similar in configuration .

What is the difference in configuration

Comment: Basically same goal, but annotation much less verbose, clean and easy to read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml configuration versus Annotation based configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182393/xml-configuration-versus-annotation-based-configuration)