# Spring:- what is the main difference between using @autowired annotation and using "autowire" in spring xml configuration?

Tags: spring

Lately, one junior developer asked me this question:"is there difference between using @autowired annotation and using "autowire" in spring xml configuration?"

I am not able to give him an specific answer.Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xml configuration versus Annotation based configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182393/xml-configuration-versus-annotation-based-configuration)

Comment: In what context are you studying this? I'm not sure that xml configuration is worthing investing your time anymore.

Answer (score 0):

No. Spring offers multiple way of wiring up components. Depending on your system build, some may offer more advantages over other.