# How to use spring mvc, hibernate, hibernate validator together?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to use spring mvc-hibernate-hibernate validator in my project. But in the class I applied the anotations, validation and mysql anotations are overlapping. The use of these two is normally the case. Or is it done in another way?

```
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer id;

@Column(name="firstname")
@NotBlank(message="Name mustn't be empty.")
@Size(max=20,min=2,message="Your name must be between 2-20.")
@Pattern(regexp ="([a-zA-Z]+)",message="You can't enter number or symols or Turkish caracter.")
String firstname;

@Column(name="lastname")
@NotBlank(message="Last name mustn't be empty.")
@Size(max=20,min=2,message="Your lastname must be between 2-20.")
@Pattern(regexp ="([a-zA-Z]+)",message="You can't enter number or symols or Turkish caracter.")
String lastname;

@Column(name="date")
@NotBlank
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
@DateValid
String date;
```

Comment: You can use spring mvc, hibernate, hibernate validator together. There is no problem. what's your error bro?

Comment: I've found out where the fault is, but I'm gonna ask you something. Wouldn't we have created code confusion using so many anotations?

Comment: usually we use annotations and it's ok let me put an answer for this question with complete explanation for you

Comment: Please read my answer and make it accepted if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spring mvc, hibernate, hibernate validator together and there is no conflict. There is a good project that named [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/)  and you can see how to use these technologies to gether.

> Wouldn't we have created code confusion using so many anotations?

This is jhipster user class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_REGEX)
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String login;

@JsonIgnore
@NotNull
@Size(min = 60, max = 60)
@Column(name = "password_hash", length = 60, nullable = false)
private String password;

@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
private String firstName;

@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
private String lastName;

@Email
@Size(min = 5, max = 254)
@Column(length = 254, unique = true)
private String email;

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false)
private boolean activated = false;
```

Usually there are two types of configuration in java

- Annotations
- XML configuration

For more information visit [annotation vs xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182393/xml-configuration-versus-annotation-based-configuration)